# Request or Chance Permission from an other App

Tags: android, permissions

In my app I try to recreate the representation of the permission as in the system, where the user can give or take away the permission of another app through a switch. Is there any way to change the permission of another app programmatically? Or is this only possible via the settings page from Android?

Comment: no, 3rd-party app can't manage permissions of other apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> where the user can give or take away the permission of another app through a switch.

**Not Posssible** , You can not control other app trough your own app

> Is there any way to change the permission of another app programmatically?

**AFAIK** that is not possible

> is this only possible via the settings page from Android?

**YES**